# Finding group wise duration in an grouped r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R dataframe like this.

```
timestamp         Value ref
19-07-2019  02:46   7   1
19-07-2019  02:47   5   1
19-07-2019  02:48   2   1
19-07-2019  02:49   4   1
19-07-2019  02:50   7   1
19-07-2019  02:51   0   1
19-07-2019  02:52   3   1
19-07-2019  02:53   3   1
19-07-2019  02:54   10  1
19-07-2019  02:55   1   0
19-07-2019  02:56   3   0
19-07-2019  02:57   10  2
19-07-2019  02:58   7   3
19-07-2019  02:59   0   3
19-07-2019  03:00   9   3
19-07-2019  03:01   7   3
19-07-2019  03:02   10  3
19-07-2019  03:03   7   4
19-07-2019  03:04   10  4
19-07-2019  03:05   0   0
```

I want to find the difference between first and last timestamp in each group other than `0`. SO for group `1` start time will be : `19-07-2019  02:46` end will be `19-07-2019  02:54`

Output format is a dataframe with three columns: `Duration  start_value  end_value`

Where `duration` is the time difference , `start_value` is the first `Value` in that group, `end_value` is the last `Value` in that group
From this example output will have `4` rows as we have `4` groups other than `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the timestamp to `POSIXct` and get `max` , `min` and difference between them in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")) %>%
  group_by(ref) %>%
  summarise(start_value = min(timestamp), 
            end_value = max(timestamp), 
            duration = end_value - start_value)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#    ref start_value         end_value           duration
#  <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>  
#1     0 2019-07-19 02:55:00 2019-07-19 03:05:00 10 mins 
#2     1 2019-07-19 02:46:00 2019-07-19 02:54:00  8 mins 
#3     2 2019-07-19 02:57:00 2019-07-19 02:57:00  0 mins 
#4     3 2019-07-19 02:58:00 2019-07-19 03:02:00  4 mins 
#5     4 2019-07-19 03:03:00 2019-07-19 03:04:00  1 mins
```

We can also use `difftime(end_value , start_value)` to get output in specific units.

---

To reorganize data with specific columns we can do

```
df %>%
  filter(ref != 0) %>%
  mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")) %>%
  group_by(ref) %>%
  summarise(start_time = min(timestamp), 
            end_time = max(timestamp), 
            max_value = max(Value), 
            min_value = min(Value), 
            duration = end_time - start_time) %>%
   data.frame()
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(1:20, .Label = c("19-07-201902:46", 
"19-07-201902:47", "19-07-201902:48", "19-07-201902:49", "19-07-201902:50", 
"19-07-201902:51", "19-07-201902:52", "19-07-201902:53", "19-07-201902:54", 
"19-07-201902:55", "19-07-201902:56", "19-07-201902:57", "19-07-201902:58", 
"19-07-201902:59", "19-07-201903:00", "19-07-201903:01", "19-07-201903:02", 
"19-07-201903:03", "19-07-201903:04", "19-07-201903:05"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 
7L, 0L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 0L), ref = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: `Column timestamp is of unsupported class POSIXlt ` I am getting this error

Comment: I converted it into as.numeric.Then it is working. How to organize in this column format `start _time  end_time  max_value min_value  duration`

Comment: @VictorJohnzon Are you sure you are using `as.POSIXct` and not `as.POSIXlt` ? It seems to work for me without any error. Also for your other question, I have updated the answer.

Comment: It is working now. Sorry My mistake. I was using as.POSIXct and not as.POSIXlt. Also I want get the value at the time of max and min timestamp and not the max and in value in thegroup

Comment: Also How to remove` # A tibble: 5 x 4
#    ref start_value         end_value           duration
#  <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>  ` these extra things above and below column names

Comment: Also 0 is not ommitted `#1     0 2019-07-19 02:55:00 2019-07-19 03:05:00 10 mins `

Comment: @VictorJohnzon I have updated the answer to remove 0 groups and added `%>%
   data.frame()` in the end to remove those "extra" things.